# How do you make custom icons for bullet points in html/css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, list

I am working on a homepage for my website and I am trying make a custom bullet point. I have the file uploaded to the image folder of the project I am working on, but everytime I test to see if it works nothing comes up. I have it in the css under the ul tag as list-style-image: url('dash.gif') and I have two script commands on the HTML that are doing trying to do the same thing with each of them being

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myUL").style.listStyleImage = "url('dash.gif')";
    }
</script>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myUL").style.listStyleImage = src = "dash.gif";
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to fix this? Any help would be appriecated.

Comment: **document.getElementById("myUL").style.listStyleImage = "url('https://via.placeholder.com/20x20')";** does work. Since that works, are you calling the function at all? Are you referencing the correct path for the image?

Answer (score 1):

I would try it with css

```
#myUL > *{
position: relative;
}
#myUL > *:before{
 content: "";
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 background-img: url("your-url");
 position: absolute;
 right 100%;
 }
```

Comment: I entered the code that you suggested but that didn't change the problem. I don't know if this is because of an error with the list being inside of two divs or something else overwriting the code.

Comment: Did it work already, if not can you post the html

Comment: It did not already work. here is a link to the github repo
https://github.com/liamoc49/PortHomepage.git

Comment: Your url is wrong it has to be "images/dash.gif"

Answer (score 0):

You can import `dash.gif` but it will be too large because it doesn't scale down. If you want create custom list-style-type use `svg` format to it. If you want just dash before `li` add this.

```
li::before {
   content: "-"
}
```

and change already exist `li::before` to `li::after` like that

```
li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 120%;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #18272F;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

li:hover::after {
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: I tried entering in the code you sent me as function myFunction() {document.getElementById("myUL").style.listStyle = "url('dash.gif')"; but that didn't change anything. Did I enter in the code the wrong way or am I doing something the wrong way.

Comment: do you call that function myFunction()? If no then add list-style to css

Comment: write that code inside css file or tag <style>...</style>

Comment: Did I need the myFunction() in there or was that just a placeholder from where I got the code from? and I tried both versions you suggested and nothing changed. Here is a link to the github repo if you that might help.
https://github.com/liamoc49/PortHomepage.git

Comment: One last question how would I make so that the dashes are on the same line as the text?

Comment: delete `display:grid;` from `li` in css